# Let $n\in \mathbb{N}, 1\lt n$, prove that $2^k {\lceil n/2^k\rceil }^3\lt n^3$ for every $k=1,..., \lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}, 1\lt n$, prove that $2^k {\lceil n/2^k\rceil }^3\lt n^3$ for every $k=1,..., \lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor$. 
I this this thanks to @J.G. Its in spanish though[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0\lt\lceil n/2^k\rceil\lt n/2^{k-1}$, $2^k\lceil n/2^k\rceil^3\lt n^3/2^{2k-3}<n^3$ for $k\ge 2$. For $k=1$ the required result is equivalent to $\lceil n/2\rceil\lt n/\sqrt[3]{2}$, which is true provided $n/2+1\le n/\sqrt[3]{2}$ and hence whenever $n\ge 4$. The cases $n=2,\,n=3$ can be checked separately viz. $1\lt\sqrt[3]{4}$.

Comment: Why is this true: $0\lt\lceil n/2^k\rceil\lt n/2^{k-1} $ ?? Shouldnt be $0\lt\lceil n/2^k\rceil\lt \lceil n/2^{k-1} \rceil$ ??

Comment: @user586431 Define $x:=n/2^k$ so $x\ge 1$. Hence $\lceil x\rceil\lt x+1\le 2x$.

Comment: thank you so much. I did post the solution

Comment: @uder586431 We discourage the inclusion of text as images, handwritten or otherwise, because they're non-searchable.

Comment: I know. It's part of an exercise I need to send. And I'm very slow writing with tex code sorry